# How to sort items in Google Sheet with custom criteria

Tags: google-sheets

I am having items in my Google Sheet under a priority column.

**Priority**

```
Must have
Could have
Must have
Should have
Should have
```

I want to apply the sorting so that all "must have" values are on top then "should have" and then "could have".

Comment: If you don't use Excel, don't tag with Excel. The two products are not the same and there are considerable differences in functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=ArrayFormula(sort(A1:A5,match(A1:A5,{"Must have","Should have","Could have"},0),TRUE))
```

[Infoinspired](https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/sort-by-custom-order-in-google-sheets/)